# Php script terminates prematurly on client abort

Tags: php, client, execution, abort

My php terminates with `header("location http//www.site.com")` command directed at an outside domain. It suppose to wake up the domain for some data reading. But that's not the issue.

It works fine up to a certain situation in which I close the html that  initiated the php prematurely.

The php executes everything apart from calling the outside domain.

I tried using the on abort command telling php to finish execution on abort of client side  but....nada.

My last header location redirection does not execute on client abort.

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Just elaborating.its an html that updates a json file on server. Once its changing enother domain should be notified to check the new updated json.  Notifying is done by calling the domain by poking it with header location etc etc.

Comment: add code - agrega código :)

Comment: The correct header directive should be: `header("Location: http://www.example.com");`

Comment: I implemented the header directive correctly.and it worked fine.the question related to premature ending of client .ie what happens when user close browser by mistake prematurly.any ideas?